# Compiler do not provide autocomplete for environment variables for NodeJs Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, environment-variables

I am using [this template](https://github.com/chriswells0/node-typescript-template) for my project. I want to use some environment variables but before i needed to set types for these variables. I have create environment.d.ts file and put this code:

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJs {
    interface ProcessEnv {
      host: string;
    }
  }
}
export {};
```

Then i tried but it did not autocomplete these varibale in process.env module. I tried to add environment.d.ts file to typeRoots but it did not worked too. How should i proceed?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "typeRoots": ["src/types", "node_modules/@types", "types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "types", "dist"]
}
```

1. Tried to add `environment.d.ts` to typeRoots